# Understanding why there are gaps where nothing is loading in the network tab in an Angular app on startup

Tags: angular

[image: network tab]

Hi, I need help understanding how to make my Angular app load faster on startup. I've labeled on the screenshot the network calls that are loading from the network tab.

The app is hosted on S3 sitting behind CloudFront.

Chunk 1 looks to be loading the main Angular files like the `main.js`, the polyfills, CSS, etc.

Chunk 2 looks to be loading the core modules (auth, navigation, etc).

Chunk 3 is loading `emscripten` in the `blob` request and a lazy-loaded module.

Chunk 4 begins the start of the API calls to the BE for data.

Why are there these significant gaps between 1-2, and 3-4? These 2 gaps sum up to almost 1s. My actual API calls start 1.5s after the app starts, so I want to see how I can close the gap between 1-4.

Any advice and guidance is appreciated. Let me know if I can provide any more information.

**EDIT**

Regarding chunk 4, it's mainly 2 sets of async calls:

1. The first `stage` API (about 1s) that once loaded the page will render + a bunch of other async calls that load much faster.
2. The second `document_list` API (about 1.5-3s) that loads only after the `stage` API is loaded. This can only load after the first API is done, unless I do a major restructuring of the app.

I'm working on optimizing both of these as well. I highlighted 1 and 2 in the following screenshots:

[image: stage API]
[image: document list API]

Comment: looks like it's resources that are loading... so in chunk 1 .woff2 and .ttf files take a little time (probably installing the font), and in chunk 3, it's loading blobs... not sure what it's doing with those. (writing objectURLs?)  Most of it is probably local disk writes.

Comment: gaps are most likely js parsing+executing+rendering calcucations. from the screenshot you've provided i would say optimizing part4 should be a priority, as other thing won't just be significant, even if instant

Comment: @Andrei yes i'm also working on optimizing part 4 where there is an api that takes 3s+, which is a low hanging fruit to optimize for

Comment: @pcalkins yeah the font file takes about 200ms in chunk 1. the blob in chunk 3 is a js file, which I think is from `emscripten`. the .js file in chunk 3 looks like a lazy loaded module in the app

Comment: it seems in part 4 you have a sequence of queries. can they(or at least some of them) be parallel?

Comment: @Andrei yes, part 4 is currently 2 sync blocks, where each block has a bunch of async queries. I edited the post with some details on part 4.

Comment: ahh... webassembly compiler?  Sounds like the blob is for that.  It has to compile and output JS to modify the DOM.   It's the long way around.... I think webassembly is only faster when it comes to GPU type tasks.  If you're not drawing graphs and things like that, just use JS.

Comment: @pcalkins right, in package-lock.json I can see webassemblyjs is coming from webpack, which I have as a dependency in package.json. i think i have webpack from earlier version of angular - i'm on angular 15 so i don't think it's needed. i'll look into removing webpack from my app as well then.

Comment: I found out the blobs due to emscripten are due to the heic2any library that I was using. heic2any depends on emscripten. I refactored the app to convert heic files in the backend instead, so that got rid of the blobs. I've also managed to reduce the app size by about 20%, and it seems to speed up the initial load time. My initial app size is now at 4.3mb. I'm not sure if all the initial gaps in the network tab are due to the app size or not.